# Comparing 2 columns in SQL Server and changing a column based on result

Tags: sql-server

```
+-------+-------+---------+
| data1 | data2 |  data3  |
+---------------+---------+
| 1000  | 1000  |         |
| 2000  | 2000  |         |
| 1234  | 4567  |         |
| 12    | 0     |         |
| 56    | 3     |         |
+-------+-------+---------+
```

I have a table like above in SQL Server. Is it possible to create a view or use a select statement to update column `data3` with `equals` or `less than` actual words if the data in `data2` is `=` to `data1` or `data2 < data1`?

I can find compares on the net but nothing to give a result or update a column based on the = or <.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can use a `case` expression like so:

```
select 
     data1
  ,  data2
  ,  data3 = case 
      when data1 = data2 then 'equal'
      when data1 > data2 then 'less than'
      when data1 < data2 then 'greater than'
      else 'other'
      end
from t
```

Update:

```
update t
  set data3 = case 
      when data1 = data2 then 'equal'
      when data1 > data2 then 'less than'
      when data1 < data2 then 'greater than'
      else 'other'
      end;
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the swift response. that worked perfectly. Would it be possible in the same statement to actually update a column with the data to save me running another process based upon the results ?

Comment: Worked like a charm :). I can use this in a ssis package to save me so much time.

Comment: was doing some tests on the data and am having a few problems I have changed the statement to reflect the real cases and put some random data in to test but a few lines do not make sense. Line 2, 5 and 14 are not following the rules correctly,   here is the query select 
     data1
  ,  data2
  ,  data3 = case 
   
   when data2 = '0' then 'AWAITING STOCK' 
      when data1 = data2 then 'DELIVERED'
      when data2 < data1 then 'PART SHIPPED'
      else 'Somethings Worng'
      end
from dbo.testtable
  and the table with data

Comment: 100        100        DELIVERED
200        1000       PART SHIPPED
100.001    100.00     PART SHIPPED
1000.00    1000.00    DELIVERED
323.0      23232.022  PART SHIPPED
123        123        DELIVERED
321        123        PART SHIPPED
111111     0          AWAITING STOCK
123123     0          AWAITING STOCK
20         0          AWAITING STOCK
20         16         PART SHIPPED
13         10         PART SHIPPED
1000       1000       DELIVERED
1000       999        Somethings Worng
555        542        PART SHIPPED

Comment: @JohnSpencer Are `data1` and `data2` not numeric data types in your `testtable` ?

Comment: they are both nchar(10)

Comment: @JohnSpencer Try converting them to `decimal(19,4)` or something similar.

Comment: Thanks again that worked perfectly, forgot about the data types.